# Check if number is prime-javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function isPrime(number){ 
    y=number%2;  
    if(number==2) ||  (y==0) 
        {document.write("Number is PRIME");}
    else
    {document.write("Number is NOT PRIME");}
}
```

This JavaScript function is defined to check if the argument received is a Prime number or not.

What is the error in this code?

It is not showing any output.

Comment: Write the full code . Did you call the function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has 3 problems.

1. **Logical error**: It checks whether a number is *even*, not whether it is *prime*.
2. **Syntax error**: `if(number==2) ||  (y==0)` should be `if((number==2) ||  (y==0))`.
3. **Redundancy**: `number==2` in the above expression is unnecessary since it will always evaluate to the same result as `y==0`.

Comment: Thank you so much. By mistake I typed y==0, instead of y!=0. Actually, I want to check if the number is prime.                                                                                               
 function isPrime(number){ 
     y=number%2;  
   if(number==2 ||  y!=0) 
    {document.write("Number is PRIME");}
   else
     {document.write("Number is NOT PRIME");}
 }
It is working now but after the required message display it says, 'undefined".

Comment: No worries. Sorted out. The function was not returning any thing. Thanks for your guidance.